# How to install wxPython phoenix for python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, wxpython, ipython

I have been trying to install wxPython phoenix for python 3.6 and nothig works.

I have tried:
1) using pip install
2) downloading tar/whl files and extracting its wx folder to installation folder (tried on different types of files).

Both didnt work.
If someone succeded please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: windows 10, thanks you.

Comment: If you have Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 installed (community version is okay) then you should be able to build from the Phoenix source tarball. The pip tool can do it directly from the tarball, or you can unpack the tarball and follow the instructions in README.rst. Or you can wait a few days for the buildbot to start producing wheels for Python 3.6.

Answer (score 4):

They just released wxPython 4.0 (the first Phoenix release) the wxPython source archive.

Get it by typing:

For windows:

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

For Linux:

```
pip install -U \
-f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
wxPython
```

Comment: Why do I not need to run pip3 when installing for python 3?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this will work.  I'm not a Windows user, so I can't test it.

```
   C:\python36\scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade  --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're an Anaconda user, there is a conda package for installing it.
See https://anaconda.org/newville/wxpython-phoenix

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c newville wxpython-phoenix  
conda install -c newville/label/GSECARS wxpython-phoenix
conda install -c newville/label/gsecars wxpython-phoenix
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 10 with python installed via Visual Studio 2017 Community:

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python36\scripts\pip.exe install --upgrade --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix

(I wanted to put this on a comment on user2470057's reply, but I don't have enough rep to comment)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download wheel for your platform from http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/
2. set HTTP_PROXY in your Windows CLI (because pip will pull `six`)
3. Install:

> python -m pip install
>   "wxPython-4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

```
C:\Python36-64>python -m pip install "wxPython-4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
Processing c:\python36-64\wxpython-4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six (from wxPython==4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850)
  Downloading six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, wxPython
Successfully installed six-1.11.0 wxPython-4.0.0rc1.dev3436+efbe850
```

Test:

```
C:\Python36-64>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 works well

C:\Python39\Scripts pip.exe install --upgrade --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/wxPython

Answer (score -1):

Work now:

```
pip.exe install --upgrade --pre -f https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython
```

No trusted_host is needed since `https` for `wxpython.org` and the tag `wxPython_Phoenix` changed to `wxPython`.